# Two Stacks in Assembler?

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-16, parentheses, data-segment

I am coding in 8086 assembler and I have ran into an interesting question. The topic is to evaluate parentheses. If this was a question in `Java` or `C`, I would simply define two stacks - one for numbers, and another for operands. Can I do something similar in `Assembly`? 
As far as I know, the Stack is defined in the last memory cells of the data segment. If I define another Data Segment, would I have another usable stack?

Another info: I don't know the input size in the beginning and I am supposed to make the program as efficient as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know, the Stack is difined in the last memory cells of the data segment

This is true if you're developing a .COM style program where all the segment registers have the same value and where DOS placed the stackpointer at the high end of this 64KB memory.

> If I will difine another Data Segment, will I have another useable stack?

There's no need to change the *Data Segment* to have another stack. Change the SS:SP register pair and start using the newly defined stack.
The stack extends downwards starting at `SP`. So if you had SP=4096 then the stack would be 4096 bytes. (not counting wraparound which would probably be wrong anyway)

Comment: Thank you. Than this should work?
stack 100h
push ax
push bx
...
mov ax, ss
mov bx, sp
mov ss, 0f00h
mov sp, 0f00h

And than I have one stack in ax:bx and another stack in ss:sp?

Comment: There can be only 1 stack active at a time: the one defined with SS:SP. You can setup a second memory region for stacking purposes but you need to load the full pointer to this region in the SS:SP pair.

Comment: Also an instruction like `mov ss, 0f00h` does not exist! You can't move an immediate value (number) in a segment register.

Comment: Thanks. can I activate both stacks not simultanisly? meaning- can I define ss, sp, and push to this stack, and later define new ss, sp and push to that stack? 
Later I will pop from each stack in it's turn, and define ss, sp before each pop. Will it work?

Comment: That's exactly how you can do this.

Comment: Considering I don't know the unput size, how can I decide where to start the "second" stack in? can I take, like: mov ax, 1000h  mov ss, ax?
it will give me 16^3-2 cells to use in the first stack, but won't it overrun other data?

Comment: Assuming that you're writing a .COM program and that it realistically will not be too long, I would recommend to only work with changing the SP stackpointer. Have the first stack at SP=0xD000 and the second one at SP=0xE000. Leave all the segment registers intact, so CS=DS=ES=SS.

Comment: Thanks.
In my case, I need to push data to both stacks one at a time. It means that I must have a pointer for each stack right? otherwise I will overrun data in the stack, since I returns sp to the same point every time...

Comment: Correct. As it is you're best of with 3 stacks! One for the *numbers*, one for the *operands* and one for the *normal stacked items* like `call`, `ret`, `int`, ...

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use two [stack data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) to evaluate expressions like `((a+b) + (c))`?

You can use the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (`sp`) for one of them, if you're careful to check that syntax errors in the input don't crash your program.  (e.g. compare `bp` with `sp` to detect when you've emptied the stack data structure that you're storing on the call stack).

Don't change `sp` to point to the other stack data structure; use a different register (like `si`) to access it.

You could use `lodsw` to pop into ax (with the direction flag set appropriately for the direction you have your stack growing).  Or use `stosw` to push ax onto a stack pointed to by `di`.  But since they use different index registers, it's not worth it (especially not changing the direction flag all the time).

So for the second stack data structure, just use normal `mov` loads/stores and `add/subb si, 2` as appropriate.

If it proves inconvenient to keep one of the stacks on the call stack (`sp`), then don't do that either.